# Combined JavaScript and Jquery functions together

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about combining these two JavaScript and Jquery functions below into either one JavaScript or one Jquery function.

All this one does is go to a url when the function is initiated.

```
function addToCart(){
    var productCode = document.getElementById("getquantity").value;
    location = "some url";
}
```

And this one in Jquery validates the drop down selection. If nothing is selected, then an alert to the user pops up.

```
$(".addproduct").live("click", function () {
    if ($("#getquantity")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Select Quantity!");
    }
});
```

The html that calls the functions

```
  <form id='product_qty' name="product_qty" autocomplete="off">
<div class="gadcontainer"> <img src="images/burn_control_usEN.jpg" width="350" height="225" border="0" usemap="#burn">
  <map name="burn">
    <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" onClick="addToCart(); return false;" href="#order" title="add to cart and checkout securely">
  </map>
  <span id="showprice"><font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>
  Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font></span>
  <div class="qty"> Qty:
    <select id="getquantity">
      <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
      <option value="410">(1) box $35 ea</option>
      <option value="405">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
      <option value="406">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**

Here are 3 more forms on the same page as the one above. But the one above is on every page of the site. The ones below are only on one page of the site and the one above is on this same page with them. I can't have same id's on the elements, so I gave elements id's with 1, 2 and 3 after each one. So how can I add onto the jquery function that @Matt Burland created to implement for the html code below.

```
    <form id='burn_qty' name="burn_qty" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="gadcontainer"> <img src="images/burn_control_usEN.jpg" width="350" height="225" border="0" usemap="#burn">
    <map name="burn">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" id="addToCart" title="add to cart and checkout securely">
    </map>
    <span id="showprice2"><font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>
    Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select id="getquantity2">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="410">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="405">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="406">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


    <form id='energy_qty' name="energy_qty" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="gadcontainer"> <img src="images/energy_mind_usEN.jpg" width="350" height="225" border="0" usemap="#mind">
    <map name="mind">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" id="addToCart" title="add to cart and checkout securely">
    </map>
    <span id="showprice3"><font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>
    Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select id="getquantity3">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="409">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="407">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="408">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


    <form id='lean_qty' name="lean_qty" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="gadcontainer"> <img src="images/lean_green_usEN.jpg" width="350" height="225" border="0" usemap="#tea">
    <map name="tea">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" id="addToCart" title="add to cart and checkout securely">
    </map>
    <span id="showprice4"><font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>
    Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select id="getquantity4">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="413">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="414">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="415">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. jQuery functions are JavaScript functions. You can combine them however you please. I've no idea what sort of combining you want to do to the two functions though.

Comment: The `live` method was deprecated in 2011. Don't use it for new code.

Comment: I just want to make one function instead of two if possible. The first function goes to a url when the image is clicked. The second function just checks to make sure something in the drop down selection is selected, if not then alert. I actually need as well to not be able to go to url if no selection is made in drop down. Right now it gives the alert, but still trys to go to url which is invalid because the selection was not made in drop down which sends parameters in the url.

Comment: You first function does nothing unless you call it. So wheres your code that actually calls it? And where's your HTML? Can you put it all in a fiddle?

Comment: now how would I call the jquery function in my html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".addproduct").live("click", function () {
    if ($("#getquantity")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
         alert("Select Quantity!");
    } else {
         addToCart();
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Alright, let's do it with new conditions.

First, your HTML has some input elements, like SELECT, from which you take the various options.

```
<select id="getquantity">
  <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
  <option value="410">(1) box $35 ea</option>
  <option value="405">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
  <option value="406">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
</select>
```

But your HTML doesn't contain 'name' attribute, so your forms are purely Javascript-based - there will be a click event on smth on the page, the current values are taken and the page is redirected somewhere else. If you want to change that behavior - start a new question.

Second, somewhere out there there exists an element with ' class=addproduct', it is a button, or link, or image, but it exists in your HTML. Since it is not shown, and actually doesn't matter - we just need that element to exist on your page.

Done with starting conditions. Now, we want to use a single JQuery script to handle this form.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ## First things first - .live() is deprecated. Let's use .on()
    $(".addproduct").on("click", function () {
        ## Using JQuery syntax we take the .val() of the select element
        var myval = $("#getquantity").val();
        if (!myval) {
             alert("Select Quantity!");
        } else {
             ## Let's build some url and go there
             var url = '/product_view.php?id=' + myval;
             window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe the OP just wants one function. You're still calling a second function in your `else` clause. Simple solution: just move that function's code into the `else`.

Comment: It's better not to do that. Keep your logic separate.

Comment: ahh! ok but convert it to jquery. How is that done?

Comment: @Mike: As Quentin said: "convert to jquery" doesn't make sense. It's all Javascript.

Comment: still do not know how to call it into my html.

Comment: I see your edit. What is the purpose of adding the $( document ).ready(function() { to the function?

Comment: The script will execute after the page fully loads.

Answer (score 0):

So making some huge assumptions because your question is unclear.

```
// I'm assuming .addproduct is the image you are clicking on
$(".addproduct").on("click", function () {                  // use on, not live
    var quant = $("#getquantity");
    if (quant[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Select Quantity!");
    }
    else {
        var productCode = quant.val();    // not sure what you are doing with this since you don't use it
        location = "some url";
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFZSF/)

Comment: just edited my post to show the html that calls it.

Comment: not sure how to call this. I'm not very familiar with jquery.

Comment: You don't call it from your HTML. You put it in the doc ready function `($(function() {..your code here..});` It will execute when the dom has loaded, adding an event handler to your `.addproduct` element(s) and will be executed `on` the `click` event. This is better than inlining your event handlers and is considered best practice because it separates your code (the JS) from your view (the HTML)

Comment: @Mike: It would *really* be worth your time to take an afternoon and work through some basic jQuery tutorials.

Comment: got a good link for me to start at? It is like Chinese to me.

Comment: start with [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tutorial&oq=jquery+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2855j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8). Even though the first result is W3Schools, it's not a terrible tutorial. The [second result](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) you could read up to the first full example and probably get enough information to get you going.

Comment: I updated my post again with more html forms that riside on same page that have different ID's. Trying to figure out how to use the same function for them too.

Comment: @Mike: If you look at my fiddle, I gave the `area` that you had the click handler on an id of `addToCart`. Change that to a class instead and use the class select `.addToCart` rather than `#addToCart` for each of your forms and all of them will call this method. But you'll need to change the `#getquantity` selector to select the right one. There are various way to navigate from the node that triggered the event to the associated `select` element. Read up on it on the jquery site because nobody here is going to write your whole application for you.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said. I changed to class on other functions to do that before. Wasn't thinking right now cuz brain is fried from being up all night.

Comment: yep, still can't get the #getquantity selecting the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addToCart(){
  var productCode = $('#getquantity')[0].selectedIndex;
  if (productCode <= 0)
     alert("Select a product");
  else{
     var quantity =  $('#getquantity').val();
     location = "some url";
  }
}
```

Simply do this.

You addToCart() is already binded to the onClick function of your area. So if you don't want to change this, just put all the code in addToCart(), like i done.

Also, if you want to delete the onclick() binding in html, Matt Burland answer is the right one

Comment: yep got it. I want to delete the onclick() binding in html. @matt-burland code works the way I want.